# Dynamic symmetry grid

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am developing a WPF application.

I have list of buttons (for example).
The list is created on run time, and on design time I don't know how many elements(buttons) are going to be in the list.
I want to order the elements in a symmetric way based on the number of buttons.

For example:

- If the list contains 4 buttons, I want the grid to have 2 rows and 2
  columns.
- If the list contains 6 buttons, I want the grid to have 2 rows and 3
  columns.
- If the list contains 9 buttons, I want the grid to have 3 rows and 3
  columns.

Is there a way to create this kind of grid?

What panel should I be using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WPF Grid container control. Add RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions to the Grid as per your requirement.
Another approach is to use a WrapPanel with a fix ItemHeight and ItemWidth.